# Cairo and Gdk.Window with Gtk.DrawingArea using python gobject-introspection and gtk3

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk3, cairo, gobject-introspection

I am trying to follow the **Gtk+ v3 tutorial** found in the reference documentation. Specifically the first Drawing example using `cairo` to handle the drawing onto a `Gtk.DrawingArea`.

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s03.html

For reference, I am using these resources:

https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/

Please take a look at my (partial) translation of the `ch01s03` program into python. The main problem I have is with `configure_event_cb()` where the program should create a `cairo.Surface` object connected to a `Gdk.Window`. I do not know how to get at this `Gdk.Window` or even where to look in the reference documentation.

```py
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, cairo

surface = None

def clear_surface():
    global surface
    surface = cairo.Surface()
    surface.set_source_rgb(1,1,1)
    surface.paint()

def configure_event_cb(wid,evt):
    global surface

    if surface is not None:
        surface.destroy()
        surface = None

    '''
    Here, I am trying to implement the following C code:

    surface = gdk_window_create_similar_surface(
                gtk_widget_get_window(widget),
                CAIRO_CONTENT_COLOR,
                gtk_widget_get_allocated_width(widget),
                gtk_widget_get_allocated_height(widget) );
    '''

    clear_surface()
    return True

def close_window(wid):
    global surface
    if surface is not None:
        surface.destroy()
    Gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
    win.set_title('Drawing Area')
    win.connect('destroy',close_window)
    win.set_border_width(8)

    frame = Gtk.Frame()
    frame.set_shadow_type(Gtk.ShadowType.IN)
    win.add(frame)

    da = Gtk.DrawingArea()
    da.set_size_request(100,100)
    frame.add(da)

    da.connect('configure-event',configure_event_cb)

    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: why did you add `cb` for the functions names? what is this referring to?

Comment: I used cb to indicate a call-back.

Comment: Why does 'surface' have to be a global variable? I tried making it an attribute of Window, but it breaks the ability to draw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have understood that the DrawingArea use the *draw* event now instead of the *configure-event* here is a simple code that works:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

def draw_cb(widget, cr):
  cr.set_source_rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
  cr.rectangle(50,75,100,100)
  cr.fill()
  return False

win = Gtk.Window()

win.set_title("test")
win.set_default_size(800,600)
win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
da=Gtk.DrawingArea()
da.connect('draw', draw_cb)
win.add(da)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

But instead if you really want to create a cairo context in the callback of the expose-event, just use this to get the gtk.gdk.window:

```
myGdkWindow = mywin.get_window()
cr = myGdkWindow.cairo_create()
```

Comment: the *draw* event is already used in the example and I was able to find examples just like this. I guess my question is more about how to get the ``cairo`` ``Context`` object (``cr`` in your case) without using the *draw* event.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of the (accepted) answer from @cedlemo I was able to recreate the `ch01s03` `Gtk+` example in `python`. However, I had to import `cairo` *actual* since the `gi.repository.cairo.Context()` constructor didn't exist. This was not obvious at first, but maybe it makes sense. Here is the fully working version. See for the [original `C` version with comments.](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s05.html)

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import cairo


surface = None


def clear_surface():
    global surface

    cr = cairo.Context(surface)
    cr.set_source_rgb(1,1,1)
    cr.paint()

    del cr


def configure_event_cb(wid,evt):
    global surface

    if surface is not None:
        del surface
        surface = None

    win = wid.get_window()
    width = wid.get_allocated_width()
    height = wid.get_allocated_height()

    surface = win.create_similar_surface(
        cairo.CONTENT_COLOR,
        width,
        height)

    clear_surface()
    return True


def draw_cb(wid,cr):
    global surface

    cr.set_source_surface(surface,0,0)
    cr.paint()
    return False


def draw_brush(wid,x,y):
    global surface

    cr = cairo.Context(surface)
    cr.set_source_rgb(0,0,0)
    cr.rectangle(x-3,y-3,6,6)
    cr.fill()
    del cr

    wid.queue_draw_area(x-3,y-3,6,6)


def button_press_event_cb(wid,evt):
    global surface

    if surface is None:
        return False

    if evt.button == Gdk.BUTTON_PRIMARY:
        draw_brush(wid,evt.x,evt.y)
    elif evt.button == Gdk.BUTTON_SECONDARY:
        clear_surface()
        wid.queue_draw()

    return True


def motion_notify_event_cb(wid,evt):
    global surface

    if surface is None:
        return False

    if evt.state & Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK:
        draw_brush(wid,evt.x,evt.y)

    return True


def close_window(wid):
    global surface

    if surface is not None:
        del surface
        surface = None

    Gtk.main_quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = Gtk.Window()
    win.set_title('Drawing Area')
    win.connect('destroy',close_window)
    win.set_border_width(8)

    frame = Gtk.Frame()
    frame.set_shadow_type(Gtk.ShadowType.IN)
    win.add(frame)

    da = Gtk.DrawingArea()
    da.set_size_request(100,100)
    frame.add(da)

    da.connect('draw',draw_cb)
    da.connect('configure-event',configure_event_cb)

    da.connect('motion-notify-event',motion_notify_event_cb)
    da.connect('button-press-event',button_press_event_cb)
    da.set_events(da.get_events() | Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | Gdk.EventMask.POINTER_MOTION_MASK)

    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```